# Error on Ruby on Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to do the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutoriel and I have a problem I don't understand..

I trying to do the part **5.10 Adding Some Validation** with the update function but i have an error "We're sorry, but something went wrong." and nothing else...

I'm sorry for all the code, but i'm a begginer and i realy don't know where is the error :/

The controller :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end

def new
  @article = Article.new()
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end 

def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])  
  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

And if i delete the if/else/end on the update function, it's work (put an other error but not only the sorry message)

-----------------[ **EDIT** ]--------------------

I have read the log file and I think this line can help you :/

```
Started GET "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-22 14:06:02 -0400

SyntaxError (C:/Users/Stephane/Desktop/rails_projects/fist_app/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:32: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
C:/Users/Stephane/Desktop/rails_projects/fist_app/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
    else
 ^):
```

Comment: See your log file,there should be an error.

Comment: I think the problem is @article.update(article_params). Can't really explain why or how to fix it without an error message... but it seems wrong.

Comment: Yeah i understand but the tutoriel say to validation like that... and the code didn't work :/

Comment: Ah! Pixel Circus! Le monde est petit ... Open your Server console and copy-paste the error backtrace in your post, we can't help you without  knowing the error -- Also, are you running your server in development environment?

Comment: I have update my post with log error

Comment: It seems you have some non-ASCII character in line 32, delete the line and write it again (manually)

Comment: Ah, tu utilises des accents dans des fichiers `.rb`, ce qui foire l’interprétation de ceux-ci. Ajoute tout en haut du fichier, en toute premiere ligne `# encoding: UTF-8`. Ceci force le reader du fichier à utiliser l'encodage UTF-8, qui est compatible avec les accents!

Comment: Thank MrYoshiji ! but I don't use accents... I delete and write the line 30 to 32, and It's work !!! :D !! Oo ?

Comment: @Sparda - no it isn't the file is just indented wrong...

Comment: @UriAgassi, This is what a think, but i reindent all the file, and i have the same result.

Comment: @Sparda - `private` is not a block - it does not need `end`

Comment: Thank, it's a second error I have, but with an error message (more easy to find the bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an invisible control character in your text (perhaps from cut and paste). Try deleting the if/else statement and retype it by hand. I know this sounds strange but have seen this kind of thing happen many times.

Comment: Work ! I have try that when @UriAgassi found it

Comment: Ah. I see this was answered in the comments while I was typing my answer :). Glad it worked out for you